# How to display HTML code in UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I have HTML code that I get from a  web service - it has style tags,(CSS I think)  images and that sort of thing. I want to display it in a web view and have the remote images load as well as all the styling.

I've tried to set it like this:

```
    [self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.itemDecription];


[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
[myString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:myString baseURL:nil];
```

However the web view just shows text without any styling and images don't load.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the 'HTML'

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
 NSString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tag" ofType:@"html"];
 NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 [webView loadHTMLString:myString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I load my NSString into those strings?

Comment: i can't get you properly .